# How to create an unordered list in a php file

Tags: php, list, unordered

Sorry if this is quite basic; I have created custom fields in Wordpress and used the following to display the fields on each product page. I'm struggling to work out how to get them to show on separate lines like an un-ordered list.

```
<div id="customfield-meta">
<?php
// Display Custom Field Value
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, ' Model_Released', true ); 
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, ' Property_Released', true );
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Catalogue_Number', true );
?>
</div> <!-- end #customfield-meta -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="customfield-meta">
<?php
// Display Custom Field Value
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>".get_post_meta( $post->ID, ' Model_Released', true )."</li>"; 
echo "<li>".get_post_meta( $post->ID, ' Property_Released', true )."</li>";
echo "<li>".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Catalogue_Number', true )."</li>";
echo "</ul>";
?>
</div> <!-- end #customfield-meta -->
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Check out w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/html/) for some basics on HTML.

An unordered list is a `<ul>` tag, though any block level html tag wrapping (or line break) will give you entries on separate lines.  You could wrap your elements with `<div>` or `<p>` tags, or you could append them with `<br/>` tags.  There are a host of different ways to accomplish what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to wrap the returned data from your php code in an unordered list, you would do so like this

```
<div id="customfield-meta">
<ul>
<?php
// Display Custom Field Value
echo "<li>" . get_post_meta( $post->ID, ' Model_Released', true ) . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>" . get_post_meta( $post->ID, ' Property_Released', true ) . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Catalogue_Number', true ) . "</li>";
?>
</ul>
</div> <!-- end #customfield-meta -->
```